# JavaScript bubble sort modification (condition of the loop "for" is not working)

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

Loop "i" must break, when if statement of loop "j" return `swap = false`, but it doesn't do that, and proceeding through all of `arr.length`

[bubble sort pen link](https://codepen.io/dandgerson/pen/XgVRKb)

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
var n = arr.length;
var t;
var swap;

for (var i = 0; (i < n) && (swap = true); i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < ( n - (i + 1) ); j++) {


    if ( arr[j] > arr[j + 1] ) {

        t = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = t;
        swap = true;

    } else { swap = false }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line

```
for (var i = 0; (i < n) && (swap = true); i++) {
```

assigns a value to swap (i.e. swap = true), whereas you actually want to check its value (.i.e. swap **===** true).

Note that swap is initially undefined, so if you change your code in line with the above (swap === true) you may want to explicitly set it to true before entering the loop.

Comment: thanks, your answer is correct and helpfull for my idea with breaking the loop "i". but my idea was wrong.

And this check doesn't work with all possible values of the array. Sorting does not happen in some cases. for example 'var arr = [11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13];'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the break; statement to stop the for() loop
[Have a look here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
var n = arr.length;
var t;
var swap = true;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
 if (!swap) {
  break;
 }
 for (var j = 0; j < ( n - (i + 1) ); j++) {
  if ( arr[j] > arr[j + 1] ) {
   t = arr[j + 1];
   arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
   arr[j] = t;
  } else {
   swap = false;
  }
 }
};
alert(performance.now());
alert(arr);
```

Comment: thanks, but why my code is not working? where my mistake? i need my loop "i" stoped, when sorting will be done

Comment: Sorry, I just put an example to help you, changes :
- set swap to true
- remove test of swap in the for() statement
- test swap inside the loop to break it if swap false

Comment: Another edit, I remove the break; from the second loop

Comment: thanks your answer is correct and helpfull for my idea with breaking the loop "i". but my idea was wrong.

And this check doesn't work with all possible values of the array. Sorting does not happen in some cases. for example 'var arr = [11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13];'

Comment: In case you need more functions like this one, you should consider using Lodash (prefered) or Underscore maybe

Answer (score 0):

[correct answer by duncan smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875529/7360033)

this line

```
for (var i = 0; (i < n) && (swap = true); i++) {
```

assigns a value to swap (i.e. swap = true), whereas you actually want to check its value (.i.e. swap === true).

Note that swap is initially undefined, so if you change your code in line with the above (swap === true) you may want to explicitly set it to true before entering the loop.